# Use user-defined asset servers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I'm building an application in Rails where sets of images can be created, i.e. the user uploads a file of image names and specifies a path where those images can be found on the web.

So, for example, the image file contains:

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

and the path is specified as `http://www.user1-server.com/`.

Another user could load his own file of image names, but specify another server: `http://www.user2-server.com/` or even `http://my-fancy-server.com`.

Is there any way to use the `AssetTagHelper` functionality of Rails to help me generate the image tags?

So, if I'm in the context of user 1, e.g. `/users/1/images/1`, and use:

```
image_tag("1.jpg")
```

it should deliver `http://www.user1-server.com/images/1.jpg`, but for `/users/2/images/1` it should return `http://www.user2-server.com/images/1.jpg` or `http://my-fancy-server.com/images/1.jpg`.

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of servers or is there N number based on # of users? www.user23423423-server.com?

Comment: I updated the question above. The user should actually be able to define his own server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change asset host in Rails on the fly like that. Rails is smart enough to not set or override the host passed into an image tag, though. Maybe just write a helper method or something to pass the correct host in?

Comment: I figured that that's probably the only alternative, but maybe somebody has a really straightforward idea.